# Flexlayout not working with angular universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-flex-layout

I have created an angular universal and pwa app. I am creating a navbar using mat-toolbar with flexlayout.

I have imported both FlexLayoutModule,FlexLayoutServerModule in my module.

My example navbar is

```
<div [hidden]="loading" class="example-container">
  <mat-toolbar class="example-toolbar">
    <span>Navigation</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <div fxShow fxHide.lt-md>
      <a href="#" mat-button>Menu Item 1</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button>Menu Item 2</a>
    </div>
    <div fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>
      <a href="#">Show Side Menu</a>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working meaning...?

Comment: @David Its not hiding or showing the particular element based on the window screen

Comment: And it works properly when you are not using universal?

Comment: Yup its working fine without universal

Comment: Is it related to https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/373

Comment: @David Thanks for the information the issue is fixed i have imported FlexLayoutServerModule incorrectly

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to import the FlexLayoutServerModule after the FlexLayoutModule.

```
 imports: [
    ... other imports here
    FlexLayoutServerModule
  ]
```

This import should happen in your ServerModule.

Here is a link that shows the proper use of the FlexLayoutModule with Angular Universal: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Using-SSR-with-Flex-Layout 
As a note if you are including the FlexLayoutModule in a lazy loaded Module there still might be issues. Those issues should hopefully be resolved with the release of v6.

Comment: I have imported the FlexLayoutServerModule in app module instead of server module

Comment: Has there been any progress on resolving the issue for lazy loaded modules?

Comment: @RasmusHansen Do you remember what was this particular issue? I'm about to attempt to convert my app to SSR and I have a LOT of lazy modules.

Answer (score 0):

##### Warning:

Make sure NOT to add `FlexLayoutServerModule` to anything that will be loaded by the browser. DO NOT add it to `AppModule` or `MyWidgetsModule` etc.

It may cause the following error in your browser console, and will prevent your app reloading after the JS has loaded.

> Strict mode code may not include a with statement

[Uncaught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114758/uncaught-syntaxerror-strict-mode-code-may-not-include-a-with-statement)

Comment: SEO: "Why is my SSR Angular app not reloading"