# Uncaught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement

Tags: javascript, angular

I have recently updated to Angular v9 and I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with
>   statement

This is occuring in the following file:

`./node_modules/@angular/animations/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/animations.js`

This is an Angular v9 file as per the comments in the file:

> /**  * @license Angular v9.0.0  * (c) 2010-2020 Google LLC.
>   https://angular.io/  * License: MIT  */

This is occuring here, with the `with` statement:

```
module.exports = {
  Window_run: function _run(code, file) {
    if (file) code += '\n//@ sourceURL=' + file;
    with(this) eval(code);
  },
```

There is a comment above this line:

> /* Domino uses sloppy-mode features (in particular, `with`) for a few 
>   * minor things.  This file encapsulates all the sloppiness; every  * other module should be strict. */ /* jshint strict: false */ /* jshint
>   evil: true */ /* jshint -W085 */

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @DaveNewton Why is upgrading to Angular v9 causing an error in their own files due to using a `with` statement?  There is a `jshint strict: false` on this, but it is failing with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement"

Comment: What exactly is throwing the error?

Comment: @deceze I have that all in my post, what do you need to know specifically?  It's being thrown in the file I listed, with the code I listed.

Comment: What operation/IDE/linter/etc. is throwing the error? You say there's an error, you don't say where it's *from*.

Comment: When you *compile* it? When you *run* it in the browser? When you *lint* it?

Comment: @deceze At runtime in the browser.  It's failing due to the `with` statement not being allowed in strict mode, but there is a `jshint string: false` above it.  It is being ignored by the browser and fails.

Comment: Yes, `jshint` is probably only obeyed by specific linters, not the browser.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34970

Comment: Browsers aren't jshint, browsers are browsers.

Comment: I'm looking into this comment ... https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34970#issuecomment-581838896 ... this could be an issue with the scaffolded .Net Core project.

Comment: If you're getting this in the browser, then that should be expected. You have a module and modules should be automatically running in strict mode. And since the browser is now parsing a function strict mode, the parser is rejecting the `with` statement. It's possible your module system was configured differently before and modules weren't running in strict mode or perhaps now the whole bundle is changed to strict mode or something. Not sure what the change was, you just say you upgraded, so I'm guessing here.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I was searching for the solution to a similar problem. Upgrade to Angular 9 broke my app. After a lot of trial and error [this helped me](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34970#issuecomment-581838896).

Just comment out or remove the following line from `main.ts` (added by the upgrade process):

```
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. See original bug https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34970#issuecomment-581838896

Comment: This error can also happen if you import some server modules in the browser app, like FlexLayoutServerModule.

Comment: @wpfwannabe thanks. I am finally able to migrate from 8 to 11.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this line `export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60672660/12577650) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34970#issuecomment-581838896) but the issue occures only when I add `ServerModule` to imports array

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [/*AppModule,*/ ServerModule],
  //  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
// export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

when removing `ServerModule` the build executed successfully