# Strict mode code may not include a with statement

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I got an error `Strict mode code may not include a with statement` in Angular 12 with universal when building the server bundle.

I removed this line `export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60672660/12577650) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34970#issuecomment-581838896) but the issue occures only when I add `ServerModule` to imports array

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [/*AppModule,*/ ServerModule],
  //  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
// export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

when removing `ServerModule` the build executed successfully