# Angular Universal 14+ | Uncaught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement (at ${sourceUrl}) | domino

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Before any duplicate markups, this is the updated issue of many like ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114758/uncaught-syntaxerror-strict-mode-code-may-not-include-a-with-statement), [here](https://github.com/fgnass/domino/issues/153), etc.)

I've been facing 3 days to this mentioned issue, which has been asked everywhere in the world I think.

[image: Uncaught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement]

This error points to this:
[image: domino]

Any solutions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60672660/7586486) don't work anymore since Angular 14+.

What I have figured out is that this issue relates to the `domino` package that is bundled with the `@angular/platform-server` dependency.

I'm stuck in SSR development with this error, even my click events don't fire because the `main.js` script is throwing this error.

Does anyone have any experience with SSR, Angular Universal v14+? There's no meaningful and useful answer to the updated Angular. Thanks.

The project **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "landing-page",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run landing-page:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/landing-page/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run landing-page:server",
    "prerender": "ng run landing-page:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^14.1.0",
    "@types/aos": "^3.0.4",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^14.0.2",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^14.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false,
    "zlib": false,
    "net": false,
    "url": false,
    "stream": false,
    "crypto": false,
    "http": false,
    "querystring": false,
    "util": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the culprit of all evil.

> Don't use export variables defined on server-side (like in server.ts)
> in the AppModule...

Basically, this happened by my mistake and wrong import.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?>

Comment: Further context to Ben's answer here https://github.com/fgnass/domino/issues/153#issuecomment-1231534297 (sorry Ben).