# caught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement Angular 14 and I removed the file creating the error but it's still happening

Tags: angular14, angular14upgrade

I have removed the culprit line of code

```
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

and followed exactly what to do here...

[Uncaught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114758/uncaught-syntaxerror-strict-mode-code-may-not-include-a-with-statement)

and yet, I STILL get the error

```
caught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement
```

This is using Angular 14.2.0 and it makes absolutely no sense.

I don't understand.

UPDATE:

This problem happens on COMPILE and it appears 5 times in the babel-webpack folder under .angular folder.  THIS IS THE PROBLEM. I've tried deleting the .angular folder but it simply rebuilds the same 5 "with (" statements. NOTE: with ( is how I searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution!

By adding this... babel-preset-es2015-without-strict here...https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015-without-strict

ceased the strict mode error.

Also, by lowering ES2022 down to 2020 further solved the problem.